# Multiple select option to a textarea

Tags: javascript

I am still learning javascript and I have problem with my current application
From this [fiddle](http://bit.ly/Vyncl1), it's not working but it can roughly show what I want to achieve.

My output if I chose Banana & Mouse will be:
Banana is yellow
Mouse is small

I want to know how I can call the second function with just one click of the button, and how can I reuse my codes in this case as I have another 5 more select options at the end it.

Thanks!

Comment: Solved: http://jsfiddle.net/jJCm3/5/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the ids as parameters to the function and manipulate each element value accordingly.

```
function displayResult (fruitId,sizeId) {
    var selTag = document.getElementById(fruitId);
    var fruit=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
    if (fruit=="Apple") {
      fruit = fruit + " is red";
    } else if (fruit=="Orange") {
      fruit = fruit + " is orange";
    } else if (fruit=="Banana") {
      fruit = fruit + " is yellow";
    }
    selTag = document.getElementById(sizeId);
    var animal=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
    if (animal=="Elephant") {
      animal = animal + " is big";
    } else if (animal=="Mouse") {
      animal = animal + " is small";
    } else if (animal=="Whale") {
      animal = animal + " is enormous";
    }
    document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = fruit+"\n"+animal;;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bz3r/1/)

Comment: Oh! Now I get it! Thanks alot Musa!

Answer (score 0):

you could make it much simpler. but here is what you were looking for [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/6bz3r/2/)

```
function displayResult (selId) {
    var selTag = document.getElementById(selId);
    var fruit=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
if (fruit=="Apple") {
  fruit = fruit + " is red";
} else if (fruit=="Orange") {
  fruit = fruit + " is orange";
} else if (fruit=="Banana") {
  fruit = fruit + " is yellow";
}
  document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = fruit;
  animalText();
}

function animalText(){
  var selTag = document.getElementById("size");
    var _size=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;

  if (_size=="Elephant") {
  _size = _size + " is big";
} else if (_size=="Mouse") {
  _size = _size + " is small";
} else if (_size=="Whale") {
  _size = _size + " is enormous";
}

      document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = document.getElementById('mytextbox').value +"\n"+ _size;
}
```